# Maximum product of integers from an array

Tags: python, list, multiplication

Trying out a question where I'm calculating the max product possible from any integers in an array.

I've written something that works for some tests, but fails others.

```
def solution(xs):
    if len(xs) == 1:
        return xs[0]
    v = 1
    s = -1001
    nn = 0
    for i in xs:
        if i < 0:
            nn += 1
            if i > s:
                s = i
        if i != 0:
            v *= i
    if nn % 2 == 1:
        v /= s
    return str(v)
```

My theory was the maximum product could be calculated by looping through an array, multiplying each number together and then in the case of an odd number of negative numbers, divide by the largest negative.

I'm missing something, but I'm not exactly sure what.

BTW The seemingly arbitrary choice of -1001 is the limit set by the test cases.

Comment: Why are you dividing by anything?

Comment: The max product of [-2, -3, 4, -5] is 60. Multiplying all of them together produces -120, then divided by -2 produces 60.

Comment: My first comment was wrong, thought you meant larger as in more negative, sorry about that, I deleted it. Are all the numbers integers? Can't they be for example 0,5?

Comment: They're all integers, I'll change my question to add that too.

Comment: What if you get an array of zeroes? Or say a negative number and a zero, like `[0, -5]`

Comment: Isn't this equivalent to find the top m elements in the n array?

Comment: This was really useful, I've rewritten the solution in a more tangible way

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
import math


def max_product(arr, num):
    pos_sorted = sorted([element for element in arr if element > 0])
    neg_sorted = sorted([element for element in arr if element < 0], reverse=True)
    factors = []

    if num % 2:
        factors.append(pos_sorted.pop())
        num -= 1

    while num > 0:
        if pos_sorted[-1] * pos_sorted[-2] > neg_sorted[-1] * neg_sorted[-2]:
            factors.append(pos_sorted.pop())
            factors.append(pos_sorted.pop())
        else:
            factors.append(neg_sorted.pop())
            factors.append(neg_sorted.pop())
        num -= 2
    return math.prod(factors), factors


arr = [-10, 1, 2, 9, -3, 5, -2, 3, 17, 5, -2, -9, -18]
print(max_product(arr, 1))
print(max_product(arr, 2))
print(max_product(arr, 3))
print(max_product(arr, 4))
print(max_product(arr, 5))
print(max_product(arr, 6))
print(max_product(arr, 7))
print(max_product(arr, 8))
```

Output:

```
(17, [17])
(180, [-18, -10])
(3060, [17, -18, -10])
(27540, [-18, -10, 17, 9])
(137700, [17, -18, -10, 9, 5])
(743580, [-18, -10, 17, 9, -9, -3])
(3717900, [17, -18, -10, 9, 5, -9, -3])
(18589500, [-18, -10, 17, 9, -9, -3, 5, 5])
```

The explanation:

- If you have an odd number, you first take the highest value from the pos-list, as for an odd number there must be at least one positive.
- Then you take pairwise two negative or two positive numbers whichever has the higher product. The reason for that is, that you can't just take one negative as then the result would be negative. But you can't just take one positive either, as then there would be an odd number of values left of which one has to be positive, so you can take that already.

If you exhaust all your negative or positive numbers, or there are not enough to begin with, you could run into KeyErrors in the if-statement. But this can be easily checked and is left as a homework for the reader :).

Comment: I've suggested these edge cases on the main question: "What if you get an array of zeroes? Or say a negative number and a zero, like [0, -5]" Does your program solve them correctly?

Comment: There are some cases, that this program would fail. E.g. exhausting all negative or positive numbers or if you don't have enough numbers. Stuff like that, but you'd just need to check for that and handle accordingly, the overall algorithm stays exactly the same.

Comment: This is a good solution, but not for my problem. The number "num" isn't included and any number of values can be used. I probably should've been more explicit.

Comment: What do you mean with that, so you can use any size of num that gives you the biggest product? Then it is trivial, you just take the biggest even number of negative values (if one is left out, then the biggest one) and all of the positive values and you ignore the zeros.

Comment: @Mango yeah, he already solved the root of the problem, he's probably just missing some edge cases, thus my comment:D

Answer (score 0):

So I ended up rewriting the solution to incorporate a handful of edge cases I was missing.

Here's the new solution:

```
if len(xs) == 1:
    return str(xs[0])
p = []
n = []
for i in xs:
    if i < 0:
        n.append(i)
    elif i > 0:
        p.append(i)
if len(n) % 2 == 1:
    n.remove(max(n))
arr = p + n
if len(arr) == 0:
    return str(0)
v = 1
for j in arr:
    v *= j
return str(v)
```